# Can the natural logarithm be meaningfully "natural" in the category theory sense?

Tags: calculus, category-theory, soft-question, logarithms, natural-transformations

This may be more of a pun than anything else, as the two usages of the word "natural" are unrelated, but I was wondering if there was any nontrivial sense in which the natural logarithm could be viewed as an example of naturality.

Many things seem to be reframeable in the context of category theory. In the category of presheaves on $\mathbf{Set}$, the natural logarithm is indeed a natural transformation under the Yoneda embedding, but so is every other set function, so I would not consider this example to showcase a particular naturality of the natural logarithm. A sufficient construction would likely need to relate to the calculus-based properties of the natural logarithm and $e$. Ideally, does there exist a nice categorial context in which the natural logarithm exhibits naturality but no logarithms of other bases exhibit naturality?

Comment: I think "natural" logarithms are natural as in "they arise from practice and simple constructions, somehow even when unwanted": so, $e^x$ is a "natural function" to define, as is its inverse $\log$. Motivating "naturality" in category theory requires a different path, and different cultural references. I'm not even sure the history has registered why we ended up calling them "natural" besides "it's the obvious thing all cool kids are doing"... (Lately I've been reading Kromer's book)

Comment: @fosco Categories and functors were developed to make rigorous the notion of “natural equivalence” - what today we call a natural isomorphism. Many natural isomorphisms are, as the name suggests, “natural” in the sense they arise obviously. For instance, $(A \times B) \times C \cong A \times (B \times C)$ seems like a very natural conclusion. Of course, generalizing natural isomorphisms to natural transformations is a natural (pardon the word choice) move.